# header() function is not working in my live web hosting

Tags: php, header, gmail, phpmailer

I have been trying to send messages from my contact form to my Gmail with PHPMailer.

Everything seems to be working other than the header function. When the submit button is clicked the mail comes to my Gmail address with all the information but the website goes directly to the **display.php** from **index.php** whereas I have already used the header function to redirect it back to index once the mail is sent.

Surprisingly the same code is working and redirecting to index when I am trying it with xampp but when it's in the hosting it doesn't redirect? Can a good soul help me with what I did wrong ?

Thanks in advance.. Here is my code in **display.php**

**Display.php :**

```
<?php
 ob_start();

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


  if(empty($fname)){
    $err_msg = "Please Input Your Full name";
    header('location:index.php?name_error=' . $err_msg . '#contact');
  }elseif(empty($email)){
    $err_msg = "Please Provide Your E-mail address";
    header('location:index.php?email_error=' . $err_msg . "#contact");
  }elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $err_msg = "Incorrect E-mail Address";
    header('location:index.php?email_error=' . $err_msg . '#contact');
  }elseif(empty($message)){
    $err_msg = "Message box cannot be empty";
    header('location:index.php?msg_error=' . $err_msg . '#contact');
  }elseif (str_word_count($message) < 10) {
    $err_msg = "Your message must be greater than 10 words";
    header('location: index.php?msg_error=' . $err_msg . '#contact');
  }




  else{

       require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
       $mail = new PHPMailer;
       $mail->isSMTP();
       $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
       $mail->Port = 587;
       $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
       $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
       $mail->Username = 'myusername@gmail.com';
       $mail->Password = 'mypass';

       $mail->setFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['fname']);
       $mail->addAddress('myusername@gmail.com');
       $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['fname']);

       $mail->isHTML(true);
       $mail->Subject = 'Form Submission';
       $mail->Body = '<h1 align=center> Name : ' . $_POST['fname'] . '<br> Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . '<br> Message : ' . $_POST['message'] . '</h1>';

        if(!$mail->send()){
          $result = "Something Went Wrong";
          echo $result;

        }  else{
          $result = "Thank you " . $_POST['fname'] . " for contacting me !!!";
          header('location:index.php?res=' . $result . '#contact');

        }



  }

 ob_end_flush();
 ?>
```

**Index.php where it should redirect and show a msg via Get method :**

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" name="button">Küldés</button>
                                         <div class="<?=(!empty($_GET['res']))?'result py-3 text-light': '' ?>">
                                           <?php
                                               if(!empty($_GET['res'])){
                                                 echo $_GET['res'];
                                               }
                                            ?>
```

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: It is `header('Location: https://www.example.com?index.php?error=' . $error)`; Location upper case, space afterwards and absolute address.

Comment: Why are you doing output buffering? You also need to URL-encode any content you put in URLs, like `rawurlencode($err_msg)`, though that's not a great way of displaying errors, one at a time. Much better would be to accumulate *all* the errors and save them in a session. You're also using an old version of PHPMailer.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply but it is still not working